# url rewriting using htaccess for category & product in php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

please help me to complete my project its about ecommerce site in core php as i am a beginner

for my site i want seo friendly url for category, subcategory, product and product detail page....

i have pages like this :

```
mysite.com/category.php?category_slug=mobiles         : category page
mysite.com/subcategory.php?subcategory_slug=samsung   :   subcategory page
mysite.com/product.php?product_slug=galaxy-note       :   product page

and i want to rewrite these url like this :

mysite.com/mobiles        :   category
mysite.com/samsung        :   sub category
mysite.com/galaxy-note    :   product page
```

my htaccess code is

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Multiviews
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ category.php?category_slug=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ subcategory.php?subcategory_slug=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ products.php?product_slug=$1 [L]
```

any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

add page name before ^

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ category.php?category_slug=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^subcategory/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ subcategory.php?subcategory_slug=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ products.php?product_slug=$1 [L]
```

and write your url for category page as example category/mobiles/

UPDATE

The original URL:
mysite.com/category.php?category_slug=mobiles
The rewritten URL:
mysite.com/mobiles

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /category.php?category_slug=$1 [L]
```

The original URL:
mysite.com/subcategory.php?category_slug=mobiles&subcategory_slug=samsung
The rewritten URL:
mysite.com/mobiles/samsung

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /subcategory.php?category_slug=$1&subcategory_slug=$2 [L]
```

The original URL:
mysite.com/products.php?category_slug=mobiles&subcategory_slug=samsung&product_slug=galaxy-note
The rewritten URL:
mysite.com/mobiles/samsung/galaxy-note

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /products.php?category_slug=$1&subcategory_slug=$2&product_slug=$3 [L]
```

Comment: i tried it and it's working but i dont want like this

Comment: i want : mysite.com/mobiles

Comment: tell me how its define what page should use??

Comment: mysite.com/mobiles    :         RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ category.php?category_slug=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: but if i am doing the same for subcategory page then it's not working

Comment: you should modify the url according what page you want to use if for Samsung i use subcategory/samsung and so on

Comment: you mean i have to use category, subcategory and products in rules

Comment: Yes, as I write it,

Comment: but i seen some other sites the same thing what i want like url i want, they dont show that the product is under this category and subcategory

Comment: they redirect to one page only

Comment: if you won't to show page name you will have to make url as: for mobile mysite.com/mobiles for samsung will be mysite.com/mobiles/samsung and for product will be mysite.com/mobiles/samsung/galaxy-note if you want this i can write to you `RewriteRule` conditions

Comment: it would be really appreciated if you do

Comment: it means i have to do all thing in only one category page

Comment: subcategory, and  product page are useles

Comment: thanks once again , i'll do let you know after implementing your rules

Comment: no if you want show mobile category your href link will be mysite.com/mobiles ..... if you want display galaxy-note page your like will be mysite.com/mobiles/samsung/galaxy-note

Comment: hi samir... now it's working properly and now how can i redirect a user to seo friendly url cause category.php?category=mobiles and mysite.com/mobile both are accessible though it can create duplicate content issue so i don't want redirect a user seo url

Comment: Hi Gautam, user will didn't know the unfriendly url in your html code you will rewire all links with friendly url: example when you put picture for iphone 5s product your like to this product will be mysite.com/mobiles/apple/iphone-5s so your user can't know the unfriendly link.

Comment: look at this link [link](http://generalegypt.net/category/motorola/combo) see how i write the a href url in page source code

Comment: but what about search engine it crawles all the links and some other blogs i read that it's necessary to redirect automatically old url to new url

Comment: really I don't know i just read that blog [link](https://www.searchenginegenie.com/Dynamic-URLs-versus-Static-URLs.html) its look good

Answer (score 0):

category/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ category.php?category_slug=$1 [NC,L]

remove the $ sign after category/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)