# Laravel .htaccess use different URL pattern to match defined route

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling with .htaccess a little.

I have routes in routes.php like for:

```
/category/{categorySlug}
/product/{productSlug}
/tag/{tagSlug}
```

I need to use even nicer urls that looks like:

```
some-category.c.html --> /category/{categorySlug}
iphone-7s.p.html --> /product/{productSlug}
samsung-galaxy.t.html --> /tag/{tagSlug}
```

It should not use redirect, only identify url pattern ant continue further to routing with remade url. It should stay as it is on browser.

I have tried something like this with various variations with RewriteRule ^(.*).c.html$ /category/$1 [NC] but no success (all other config is default that comes with fresh Laravel 5.5 install):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Tried various flags...
    RewriteRule ^(.*).c.html$ /category/$1 [NC]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: You want to use routes like this `{categorySlug}.c.html` instead of `/category/{categorySlug}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that trying to customize `.htaccess` is the best way.

If you want to have a route like this `localhost/some-category.c.html` instead of `localhost/category/some-category`.

You should try something like that :

```
Route::get('{categorySlug}.c.html','Controller@method');
Route::get('{productSlug}.p.html','Controller@method');
Route::get('{tagSlug}.t.html','Controller@method');
```

If you still want to edit the `.htaccess`, you can give a look to those links : 
- [How to change url? htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301249/how-to-change-url-htaccess?rq=1) 
- [url rewriting using htaccess for category & product in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070981/url-rewriting-using-htaccess-for-category-product-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: Yep. In older Laravel it wasn't possible to use dots in url route. Now it seems that they've implemented that. Thanks :)